# How can i merge/combine multiple projects into one in android studio?

Tags: android

i have three separate projects in android studio say A , B and C with A being the main project,
i want B and C to be part of A, say when clicking in a button it takes me to B and another button to C.
Any suggestions guys? thanks.

Comment: have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer, i already found a solution!

Comment: if that so then consider answering your question so others that found similar problems can use your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to my problem:
first of all make sure that build.gradle of your apps in the projects you want to combine has the same information(sdk version etc.. and sync after changing), then just copy the necessary files(.java and .xml from project B to A) and make sure to change the package name starting with com. in the java files of project B to the same package name of the project A, lastly add the activities of the new java files added in the manifest.
That worked for me, hope it does for you too!